# Replace all occurences of a substring in a field in all documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection Brands, I have to replace the path ./assets/ to D:/data/db/images , I have multiple occurrences of this in multiple documents. How do I acheive this using a query ?

Sample of each document

```
{"name":"Dell","images":["./assets/dell1.jpg","./assets/dell2.jpeg","./assets/dell3.jpg"],
             "captions":["Yours is here","Easy as dell","Uniquely you"],
             "logo":"./assets/dell4.png",
             "details":{"headOffice":"Bangalore","address":"No.12/1, Divyashree Green, Koramangala Inner Ring Rd, Domlur, Bengaluru - 560071",
             "phoneNumber":"(080) 28077000  ","website":"www.dell.com"}
             }
```

Comment: I'm sure this is not the elegant way but for small collections, we use to call mongodump, sed and mongorestore. Very easy but very sysadmin-like :-)

Comment: Please explain what you're speaking

Comment: you dump your collection as a text file with `mongodumb` (keep a copy of this before any other step), then you do some text substitution with `sed` and you re-inject the modified documents to your DB with `mongorestore`. If you are not on Linux you can forget that solution. If your collection contains more than 10000 entries you better forget it also.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the `D:/` in your path. You are on windows and my solution will not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Aggregation Framework's [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) operator to redirect the output of your aggregation to particular collection. If you specify the same collection name then it will replace existing collection.

To overwrite existing field you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) operator. Then you just have to remove the length of `./assets/` using [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/index.html) and concatenate that with your new prefix using [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html)

```
db.Brands.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            images: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$images",
                    as: "image",
                    in: {
                        $concat: [ "D:/data/db/images", { $substr: [ "$$image", 8, { $strLenBytes: "$$image" } ] } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "Brands" } //replaces existing collection
])
```

In MongoDB 3.2 you can run following script:

```
db.Brands.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.images = doc.images.map(function(image){ return image.replace("./assets/","D:/data/db/images/") })
    db.Brands.save(doc);    
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using MongoDB 3.2 , is there any other workaround?

Comment: Any output you can attach ?

Comment: Please check the collection name. I've used dummy `col` just to test on my machine, changed to Brands in my answer

Comment: Well I had changed that before executing, it doesn't work tho

Comment: Perhaps you can create a new collection with the document from your post, run this script and check if it works (that's what I did) and then try to compare that data model with yours